# Java: is it possible for a client to use same port on remote computer twice?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Let me clarify the question.

See the digram [image: Digram]

Is such connection possible with all the four sockets running simultaneously!

ServerSocket is the ServerSocket from java.net API
normal Socket is Socket from java.net Api

And yes by ServerSocket I mean the socket returned from ServerSocket.accept after connection is established

Comment: With two separate machines, where do you see the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and you are not using the same socket twice when you do this. Note that machine A and B both have a socket 5050, but they are on different machines, it's not the same socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it?

Yes, it is possible as one communication end is defined by ip address and port together. As both servers will have different ip addresses there will be no problem.

Also thought about the internet? Nearly all web servers are running on port 80 and it works just fine.

Comment: Well can you tell me what port does the Socket object uses that makes a out going connection to a ServerSocket

Comment: A `Socket` uses an arbitary port (which is unbound and above 1024).

Comment: Oh! so am I actually using two ports on each machine (5050 and a arbitrary port) ??

Comment: @Allahjane Yes, you're using 2 ports on every machine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? Your question doesn't even need the reverse part of it where both peers are servers and both are clients. A server can accept any number of connections on the same port. There really isn't anything else to be said about it.

Comment: I actually need that approach! I want both Machines to act as server and clients to each other. I don't have a specific machine to be used as server. Any no of machine may join or leave.. its a mesh network

Comment: @Allahjane It doesn't make any difference. The port numbers are local to the hosts and to the TCP protocol. They aren't network-wide.

Comment: ok but actually using two sockets makes it simpler in logic for me

Comment: Sure but it still doesn't make any difference. The answer to your question is still 'yes', and it is still something that you could have tested in about two minutes for yourself, and got a definite answer, rather than wasting several times that here.

Comment: Its not important how much effort you put , but if you finally learn something

Comment: @Allahjane Of course it's important. Aren't you concerned about your own efficiency? About mine? Why should I waste my time answering questions you could have easily answered for yourself? Why should *you* waste time asking questions on forums which might never be answered, or answered wrongly, when you can get a definite and correct answer in minutes? It's not a rational mode of enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Socket is a combination of (src ipAddr/port & dest ipAddr/port). This constitutes a unique socket and only one such can exist on a machine at a given point of time.

As @EJP pointed out, yes it doesn't make any difference. For a machine, binding to port either for listening/sending data doesn't depend on other machine. Port numbers are always pertained to its own machine. 
Port numbers range from 0 to 65535 (2 bytes). 0-1024 is reserved to well-known ports. Hence while choosing a port number for a Listening Socket, choose a port >1024.

I suggest you to learn about Sockets and Ports in general terms prior to going into programming for Socket Connections in Java or whatever language.

Refer "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly54C.png". Modified the figure (look for GREEN boxes). Whenever a machine (Machine B) try to connect to a remote machine (Machine A) to a specific dest port, OS chooses a random source port on the same machine (Machine B)